# How can i have a function to swipe in from the left so that a menu slides in : Html 5 Javascript Css?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a navbar that has the similar swipe in from right function to that of apple to swipe in from the top to bring the notifications centre. I am not sure on how to do this using Html 5 and javascript for a mobile web app?

Comment: Please explain what you've already tried and post any code you've produced - you will get better answers if you've shown everyone what you've already tried.

Comment: I have not tried with any code yet because I have no clue how i would do it. At the moment i have an image positioned outside the page with userscalabe = false set and i want it to move into the page ontouch or when the user swipes in from the side.

Comment: You can use slideUp, slideDown or slideToggle features of jQuery...